# Android KeyboardView and Webview

Tags: java, android, webview, android-softkeyboard

I have an Android app that uses Webview and html text input elements.

I want to customize the keys in the keyboard to show numbers and forward slash key (/) to enter math fractions.

My question is: Will KeyboardView class help me in this case?  If so, how do I do that?  Any help is greatly appreciated